# Xamarin form: Memory usage defining datatemplate in App.xaml file

Tags: xamarin, memory, xamarin.forms, datatemplate, xamarin.forms.listview

If I define a data template in `App.xaml` instead of in `Page.xaml` or inside `ListView`, will it increase the memory usage as a whole?

Answer (score 1):

No, it should not increase the memory usage as a whole.

Defining things within `App.xaml` increases your app's startup time since the app has to load everything in the `App.xaml` page when the app first runs.

If you are using the same `DataTemplate` on multiple pages though, defining it within `App.xaml` could increase performance overall.

You could try out the [Xamarin Profiler](https://www.xamarin.com/profiler) to find out for yourself what the differences are (requires Visual Studio Enterprise Subscription).